# How can I iterate through a props and increment the values inside the props?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am trying to increment the values of the props whenever an option is clicked depending on which one I click on a mobile application. Each click takes me to the next page and each page has a list of values for example:

```
question: 'Who won?',
answers:[
            {
                answerId: 1,
                answerText: 'Blue Team',
                scores:[
                    {
                        john: 0,
                        mary: 1,
                        james: 1,
                        sarah: 0,
                    }
                ],
            },
            {
                answerId: 2,
                answerText: 'Red Team',
                scores:[
                    {
                        john: 1,
                        mary: 0,
                        james: 0,
                        sarah: 1,
                    }
            ],
}
```

If someone would click on Blue Team we would then add the scores for that answer and make the array keeping the scores have the following values:

```
{
john: 0,
mary: 1,
james: 1,
sarah: 0,
}
```

This is a snippet of the code that I am using for this

THE FUNCTION TO ADD PROPS

```
AddAnswerScoresFunction=(props)=>{
    console.log(props);
    // Sum props every time

    sum = props.reduce((a, b)=>{
      for(let k in props.reduce(b)){
        console.log("k is ", k);
        if(b.hasOwnProperty(k)){
           a[k] =(a[k] || 0) + b[k];


          console.log(a[k]);

        }
      }
    },{});
```

THE BUTTON ON WHICH WE CALL THE FUNCTION

```
<Text key={i} style={styles.answer} onPress={() => {this.AddAnswerScoresFunction(unique.scores); Vibration.vibrate(500); this.swiper.swipeLeft()}}>{unique.answerText}</Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, We can't update the value of props, As Props are [Read-Only](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#props-are-read-only). For that, you need to call the function in Parent call and update the value in it. If you want to do it in same component you can use state.

Comment: and how would you do it otherwise without modifying the props? can you help out with an example? thanks a lot

Comment: So for that, you need to pass a function from parents component same as other props. And you need to call that function when you want to update the props value.